# How can I include response data in Rails logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, controller, event-handling, response

I noticed that Rails logs show the request-response duration, which means Rails first waits for the response before logging the request parameters, and other request info.

This means the response has already been generated upon the point of logging. Is there a way to add response data to the logs?

For example: If I have an `InquiriesController#create`. I hope to include the attributes of the newly created inquiry in the log item pertaining to that request.

I've learned that you can add more stuff to the logs using data from the `ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event`, but upon inspection these don't seem include the response data as well.

Hope you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the rails log with anything you like at any time you like within your own code. Details here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger

eg you could put in the current set of data you've pulled out using the params, if that's what you want to log.

However, you can't print the response to the log until you have one... and AFAIK you only get one at the end of the process of rendering the response... no idea how you'd get access to some kind of partial response to print.

But perhaps your intent is based around an error somewhere... and you actually want to figure out where you are getting the error? If so... you can do that by logging along the way (including putting log statements into your views) and seeing where you get up to before the error occurs.